# Why local variables always point to the same place in memory?

Tags: python, scope

I was struggling with weird bug in my code. Following code is simple replication of that bug:

```
import random

array = []
for _ in range(0,5):
    rand = random.randint(0,7)
    print(f"adding lambda for rand = {rand}")
    array.append(lambda : print(rand))

for e in array:
    e()
```

My prediction was that `e()` would print exactly the same numbers as the first loop but it didn't. After some time I figured it out that `rand` is always the same place in memory and only the last change to its value will be used in lambda execution. The thing is as much as I understand how it works I don't understand why would someone possibly make programming language work this way. So here's my question: Why local variables in python point to the same place in memory even though it's not declared before the loop(scope)?

Comment: Because the function you create is closed over `rand`. And the value of `rand` is always the *last value from your loop*.

Comment: Although note, `rand` is global in this case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what would make value passed to lambda work as I expected at first?

Comment: Well, the "correct" way to do this is to *force* the creation of a local variable that doesn't change. Create a factory function, `def func_maker(rand): return lambda: rand` then use `array.append(func_maker(rand))`. There is also a common idiom in python to use (or abuse) default paramters, and you could just do `array.append(lambda rand=rand: rand)`

Comment: Because note, **you aren't passing in a value anywhere**. You are simply referencing a free variable, and that variable resolves to `rand`. So of course, it gives you the same value as what `print(rand)` would give you there. Also note, this question has noting to do with memory management.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for clearing it out.